# How to hide multiple axes plotly?

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have a plot with multiple y axes and a legend on right side. 
I want only  to show the y axis when the graph is selected on the legend.
I can hide the graphs when i click on the legend , but the axis are all visible.
How can i dynamically hide the y axes?

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3], 
  y: [40, 50, 60], 
  name: 'yaxis data', 
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2, 3, 4], 
  y: [4, 5, 6], 
  name: 'yaxis2 data', 
  yaxis: 'y2', 
  type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
  title: 'Double Y Axis Example', 
  yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'}, 
  yaxis2: {
    title: 'yaxis2 title', 
    titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
    tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'}, 
    overlaying: 'y', 
    side: 'right'
  }
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i can answer my question myself.

```
Plotly.relayout('myDiv', 'yaxis2', null);
```

that deletes the 'yaxis2' from the layout.
If you want to delete the traces belong to this axis , then delete the traces first.

```
 Plotly.deleteTraces('myDiv',[x]);   // 0 delete first trace, 1 second 2 third...
 Plotly.relayout('myDiv', 'yaxis2', null);
```

Comment: I am having the same problem.
There is no need to show the axis, when you hide the trace itself.
I do not understand how you solved the problem. Is there an onClick event for the legend items? I did not find any.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the `plot_restyle` event and then depending how flexible (and complex) you want your code to be, you can then somehow make the axis you want to hide hidden by changing the axis' `visible` property to `false` through

```
Plotly.relayout('myDiv', { 'yaxis2.visible': false });
// and to undo...
Plotly.relayout('myDiv', { 'yaxis2.visible': true });
```

For a fully dynamic example checkout https://jsfiddle.net/bytesnz/t2y3yaa3/. Note that all the yaxis have `anchor: 'free'`